# How to fill listBox Control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I get data from DB:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemShape", conn);

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

And I need to fill my control with recived data,like this :

```
         foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
           lbxObjects.DisplayMember = item["Shape"].ToString();
           lbxObjects.ValueMember = item["ID"].ToString();
        }
```

But my control is empty after Debugging any idea what is wrong with the above?

Comment: What do you see when you put a breakpoint on the `foreach` line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*sorry - I was too much into ASP.NET where my first approach would have worked - but in Winforms, it doesn't..*)

You can use something like this - load the data into a `DataTable` (so your control has all the data available) and bind that:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemShape", conn))
{
    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable tblShapes = new DataTable();
    dap.Fill(tblShapes);

    // define Display and Value members
    lbxObjects.DisplayMember = "Shape";
    lbxObjects.ValueMember = "ID";

    // set the DataSource to the DataTable 
    lbxObjects.DataSource = tblShapes;
}
```

That way, you don't have to manually iterate the list - the Listbox class will do that for you! You just need to define which collection of items to bind (by setting the `DataSource`), and which property of each item to use as `DisplayMember` and as `ValueMember`

And while you're at it - if you only need `ID` and `Shape` from that table - **say so** in your `SELECT`!

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Shape FROM ItemShape", conn))
{
```

There's no point in retrieving **all columns** if you really only need two of them ...

Answer (score 1):

use the following code:

```
while (dataReader.Read())
          {
            object ID = dataReader["ID"];
            object shape = dataReader["shape"];
            lbxObjects.Items.Add(ID.ToString() + ": " +  shape.ToString());
          }
```

Comment: Generally, I agree, it is necessary to set the listBox's DataSource property in such cases.  Anyway, I decided to show how to populate the listBox manually by iterating the DataReader

Answer (score 1):

You have to use reader as datasource of listbox

```
using( SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemShape", conn))
    {
          conn.Open();
          using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
          {
              if(reader.Read())
              {
                   lbxObjects.Text= item["Shape"].ToString();
                   lbxObjects.Value= item["ID"].ToString();
                   lbxObjects.DataSource=reader;
                   lbxObjects.DataBind();
              }
           }
    }
```

Comment: This **doesn't** work in Winforms - just tried it myself. The listbox stays empty. You need to either load the entire data into a `DataTable` or iterate yourself. In ASP.NET, the call to `.DataBind()` will do this for you - not here in Winforms, however...