# invalid attempt to read when no data is present to ListBox in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My question is about to - Invalid attempt to read when no data is present to ListBox in asp.net c# SqDataReader
My code is :

```
SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["evaConn"].ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        oConn.Open();
        SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand();
        oCmd.Connection = oConn;
        oCmd.CommandText = str;
        SqlDataReader dr = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
        lstLeft.DataTextField = "drname";
        lstLeft.DataValueField = "drid";
        lstLeft.DataSource = dr;
        lstLeft.DataBind();
        for (int j = 0; j < lstLeft.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (dr["othermr"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    lstLeft.Items[j].Text = lstLeft.Items[j].Text + " (Assigned to - " + dr["mrname"].ToString() + ")";
                }
            }
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {


    }
    finally
    {
        oConn.Close();
        oConn.Dispose();
    }
```

Error comes invalid attempt to read when no data is present to List Box in 
asp.net c# after binding the data to Listbox

Comment: Why you are using a ListBox here? And how you are declaring the ListBox? Can you show the declaration and initialisation?

Comment: I added the list box in front end side i.e. asp.net page <asp:ListBox ID="lstLeft" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="350px" Height="425px"></asp:ListBox>

Comment: Try moving `lstLeft.DataBind();` next to your for loop and check. I think you picked ugly approach. Better you create a list or datatable with required data and then simply bind it to UI, which would be much maintainable.

Comment: Seems that the `SqlDataReader` is out of data when advancing to the next loop. Try sending `SqlDataReader` contents immediately to a `DataTable` & iterate from the created `DataTable` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good practice to use `DataReader` inside for-loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < lstLeft.Items.Count; j++)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (dr["othermr"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            lstLeft.Items[j].Text = lstLeft.Items[j].Text + " (Assigned to - " + dr["mrname"].ToString() + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `DataReader` is running in one direction so that when it exits the `while` loop, it reached end of loaded data sequence, thus it can't be used to get value of non-existent record when advanced to next loop (and returns *invalid attempt to read when no data is present*).

The correct way is using a counter inside `while` loop & counts every time the data has been read until the last sequence:

```
var dr = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
int j = 0;

while (dr.Read())
{
    if (dr["othermr"].ToString() == "1")
    {
        lstLeft.Items[j].Text = lstLeft.Items[j].Text + " (Assigned to - " + dr["mrname"].ToString() + ")";
    }

    if (j == lstLeft.Items.Count)
    {
        break;
    }
    j++; // counter
}
```

I recommend to use `DataTable` if you still want to use `for` loop:

```
var dr = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
var dt = new DataTable();

dt.Load(dr); // load data into DataTable instead

for (int j = 0; j < lstLeft.Items.Count; j++)
{
    // adjust the row index number so that you can get proper values
    if (dt.Rows[j]["othermr"].ToString() == "1")
    {
        lstLeft.Items[j].Text = lstLeft.Items[j].Text + " (Assigned to - " + dt.Rows[j]["mrname"].ToString() + ")";
    }
}
```

Additionally, when binding data source to a server control from `DataReader` you should use `DataTable` (and you can reuse it with for-loop above):

```
// taken from /a/14089639
using (var oCmd = new SqlCommand(str, oConn))
{
    var dap = new SqlDataAdapter(oCmd);
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dap.Fill(dt);

    lstLeft.DataTextField = "drname";
    lstLeft.DataValueField = "drid";
    lstLeft.DataSource = dt;
    lstLeft.DataBind();
}
```

Note that you don't need to use `oCmd.ExecuteReader()` twice if on the first stage you're already putting `DataReader` contents inside `DataTable`.

Reference:

[How to fill listBox Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089610/how-to-fill-listbox-control)

Answer (score 0):

Shail,
To me, your Reader becomes empty (but not null) after you bind it with Listbox.
So, if you change you code like below, i hope it will work for you:

```
SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["evaConn"].ConnectionString);
try
{
    oConn.Open();
    SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand();
    oCmd.Connection = oConn;
    oCmd.CommandText = str;
    SqlDataReader dr = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
    lstLeft.DataTextField = "drname";
    lstLeft.DataValueField = "drid";
    lstLeft.DataSource = dr;
    lstLeft.DataBind();
    dr.Close();//Close dr here
    dr = oCmd.ExecuteReader();//fill it again here
    for (int j = 0; j < lstLeft.Items.Count; j++)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr["othermr"].ToString() == "1")
            {
                lstLeft.Items[j].Text = lstLeft.Items[j].Text + " (Assigned to - " + dr["mrname"].ToString() + ")";
            }
        }
    }
    dr.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{


}
finally
{
    oConn.Close();
    oConn.Dispose();
}
```